# Excel Count Different Values With extra if

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft

I have a large amount of data. I want to count every different data. I've found that part of my formula but I want to add ab extra if; For example, I can count different data with this formula;

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B;B:B)>0;1))
```

But I want to count that if Flag was "Yes". How can I do that? I need that for all B Column, not just B1:B7. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 conditions? 1. Count the unique value 2. FLAG is yes Is my understanding is correct? if yes, Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B2:B7,B2:B7)*(UPPER(A2:A7)="YES"))
```

[image]

Comment: That formula solves my problem but i need to do that in all columns. When I try to do that B:B it gives error.
I need this one;

=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B:B;B:B)*(A:A="Yes"))
New to the excel so i can adjust this to your formula. Thanks a lot.